# Not able to read model.pkl from output folder in Azure ML

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I'm try to read the model.pkl file from the artifacts output folder like this

```
def init():
    global model
    # infile = open('model.pkl','rb') 
    # model = pickle.load(infile)
    #model = joblib.load('model.pkl')
    model_path = Model.get_model_path(model_name = '<<modelname>>')
    model_path="outputs/model.pkl"
    # deserialize the model file back into a sklearn model
    model = joblib.load(model_path)
```

But still its not working please guide me how to read model.pkl file from artifacts output folder, because of this it is failing to deploy into Azure container instance

Comment: needs more code and more details

Comment: Do you want score.py file code

Comment: Yes please, paste in link to GitHub repo and I'll try to take a look.

Comment: Sure, i took code from this repo [link] (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/IoTEdgeAndMlSample/blob/markmyd/deviceHarnessEdgeEnabled/AzureNotebooks/02-turbofan_deploy_model.ipynb) i only changed credentials